# display image from laravel in vuejs

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

After having tried solutions such as "php artisan storage:link" , image still cannot be displayed in frontend(vuejs).

images itself are stored in "storage/public/app/xxx.png"

and the code in vuejs is
.
.
.

```
 <ul v-for="(item,v) in allItemList" :key="v">
     <li>
         <img :src="path + item.file_path" alt="">
     </li>
 </ul>
.
.
.
data: function(){
        return {
              allItemList:[],
              path: "http://127.0.0.1/api"
        }
}
```

I tried to access image via browser hitting "http://127.0.0.1:80/api/storage/xxx.png", but resulted in "Not found"

any clue would be highly appreciated.

Comment: remove `api` from the path

Comment: api should be just a path for the router, assets are under storage folder so you should find your image under http://127.0.0.1:80/storage/xxx.png as Muhammad Dyas Yaskur said.

Comment: When returning urls from an api it’s best practice to return the entire location of the asset.

So, if your image is located in Laravel’s public directory which is the root of your domain, your api should return an absolute location to the image, such as 'http://127.0.0.1:80/api/storage/images/xxx.png'

'<img :src="'/path/'+ item.file_path" alt="image" />' it is for external api

Answer (score 0):

you can create a javascript `asset()` helper function

in you main `main.blade.php` file which includes in all of your file

add this script

```php
<script>
      window.asset = function(url){
          return "{{ asset('/') }}" + url;
      }
</script>
```

or you can assign to vue instance like this

```js
<script>
    window.Vue.prototype.asset = function(url){
        return "{{ asset('/') }}" + url;
    }
</script>
```

then inside javascript you can do like `asset('image.png')`